# Can critical point that $f''$ has different sign in its every neighborhood be a local extreme point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Suppose that $f$ is a second order derivable function on $[0,1)$, and $f'(0)=0$. It is true that:

- If there exits $\delta>0$ such that $f''(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in[0,\delta)$, then $0$ is a local minimum point.
- If there exits $\delta>0$ such that $f''(x)\leq0$ for all $x\in[0,\delta)$, then $0$ is a local maximum point.

**Question:**
If  $f''(0)=0$ and for any $\delta>0$ there exits $x_1,x_2\in [0,\delta)$ such that $f''(x_1)>0$ and $f''(x_2)<0$, 
is it possible that $0$ is a local extreme point of $f$ ?

Comment: If the graph of $f$ remains between $y=x$ and $y=2x$ then there is a local minimum at $0$. Look at the intervals $[1/(n+1),\,1/n]$.  Within each such interval, you can make $f''$ assume both positive and negative values while keeping $f$ between those two lines.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Inspired by your method, i choose the upper function $y=x^6$ and the lower function $y=x^8$ to construct the function $f$ as $f(x)=x^8+(x^6−x^8)(\sin\frac1x+1)/2$, and this works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x)=1.1x^6+x^6\sin(1/x)=x^6\left(1.1+\sin(1/x)\right)$, with $f(0)$ defined to be $0$. (I suppose you may want to prove that this makes a continuous function.) Here is a picture of $y=f(x)$.

[image]

The factorization reveals that for $x\neq0$ the outputs are positive. So this function has a minimum at $x=0$.

$$f'(x)=6.6x^5+6x^5\sin(1/x)-x^4\cos(1/x)$$
$$f''(x)=33x^4+30x^4\sin(1/x)-4x^3\cos(1/x)-x^2\sin(1/x)$$
for $x>0$. Additionally, it can directly be shown using the definition of the derivative that $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=0$. And you can show that theses derivatives are continuous.

I have not pursued a formal proof, but it appears to me that $f''(x)$ takes both negative and positive values on any $[0,\delta)$. Basically, the first three terms of $f''(x)$ are negligible near $0$ compared to the last term, which oscillates in a well-understood way between $y=x^2$ and $y=-x^2$. Here is a picture of $y=f''(x)$:

[image]

So I believe this function is an example that answers your question: yes, it is possible.

---

I found this function by asking what kind of $$g(x)+h(x)\sin(1/x)$$ would meet your criteria.

Comment: That didn't really answer "yes" because $0$ is not a local extreme point of your $f.$ Something like $x^4(2 + \cos (1/x))$ will do the job though.

Comment: @zhw Yes, $0$ is. $f(0)$ is $0$, while for all other $x$, $f(x)$ is positive, as explained. So $0$ is a global minimum (and therefore local minimum.) Meanwhile, the function you proposed is not 2nd differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right. I saw your graph, and thought that was the graph of $f.$

Comment: @zhw Good point though. I'll add a picture of $f$ itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And take $f(x) = x^6 + x^6\sin(1/x)$ works too.

Comment: @wagermn That depends on the definition of "local extremum". With the function you propose, $f$ takes the value $0$ infinitely many times in any neighborhood of $x=0$. It's true that the mainstream definition of local extremum allow for this. But sometimes the definition requires that $f(0)$ is _strictly_ smaller (or greater) than everywhere else in the neighborhood. In the mainstream definition, every point of a constant function is an extremum, and that feels wrong (imho). I went with $1.1$ to cover the alternate definition too.